# New class instance for each day of the month?

Tags: ios, swift

I have built an array which contains date elements. That is, given the current date, the array is a collection of a week prior and a week preceding.

```
     // ... UIView class properties

     var dateArray = [Date]()

    // ...  UIView class properties

    func getDate() {

        // get date in raw format
        let minute: TimeInterval = 60
        let hour: TimeInterval = 60 * minute
        let day: TimeInterval = 24 * hour

        for i in -7...7 {
           let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: day * Double(i))
           dateArray.append(date)
        }
     }
```

This data (after formatting) will be used for a view presented in the background view of a UICollectionViewController, a pickerView with dates. The DataSource of the UICollectionViewController somehow needs to be dependent on the these dates. That is, the user will fill each CollectionCell with information, the activity he/she completed in that day. Selecting a new date (in the pickerview) will mean a brand new and default CollectionView DataSource.

What i want to achieve now is (1) update my UICollectionViewController based on the data which belongs to the selected day, and (2) as the days progress (in real life), old information which falls outside of my interval goes out of existence and new ones get created.

I suspect i connect my dateArray to the DataSource of my UICollectionViewController and somehow update them i just don't know how.

Any help will be very appreciated since i cannot come up with the logic to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You should always recalulate the day when the view is about to appear.  Then you run a timer periodically to check if the date has changed.  When the date changes you recalulate the dates and reload the collectionView:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var days: [Date] = []
    var lastRefreshDate: Date?
    var timer: Timer!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        refresh()
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.refresh()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    private func refresh() {
        if let date = lastRefreshDate,
            Calendar.current.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: Date()){
            return
        }
        days = (-7 ..< 8).flatMap { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: $0), to: Date())}
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return days.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DateCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? DateCollectionViewCell
        cell.date = days[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, recalculating the date as you propose makes sense. I realised that i have not written my question quite accurately (now edited). I want the DataSource to be dependent on the selected date, that is as i change the date, the data filling the cells changes to that particular day. I suspect (1) make a default data class, (2) pass date as an argument in custom init to establish dependency and finally, create an instance of this data class for each date that is live in the select date view (pickerView).